# Struct property initialization testing

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest

XCTest code coverage indicates that I should make a test for `HealthStat's id` property initialization. What is the best way to test it?

```
struct HealthStat: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let stat: HKQuantity?
    let date: Date
}
```

Comment: Test coverage does not indicate any tests. Test coverage shows you which lines of code are executed during a test run. You should use this information to think about if you need another test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is it that you are trying to test about it? With the current implementation it would be fairly hard to test anything about it as you have no control over what the value of the UUID is. In order to improve the testability you would have to inject the creation of the UUID (or the UUID itself).

For instance, you could update your code to something like...

```
struct HealthStat: Identifiable {
  let id: UUID
  let stat: HKQuantity?
  let date: Date

  init(id: UUID = UUID(), stat: HKQuantity?, date: Date) {
    self.id = id
    self.stat = stat
    self.date = date
  }
}
```

Now you can test that whatever id you pass into the model is stored in the id. But also, in production code it will get a default UUID created using `UUID()`.

But there are infinitely many varieties of how to test this sort of thing.

I guess this is the most basic version of dependency injection. The dependency in this case is the creation of UUIDs. And you have to inject it in order to make it testable.

Search for Swift Dependency Injection to read more about what it can do for you.

Comment: Yeah, I also agree about the change to the struct itself so that the uuid comes from the initializer default value rather than the property declaration.

Comment: Adding init() solved my problem. I just had to test if it sets all values correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot test what the UUID *is*. Just test that the newly instantiated object *has* a UUID and walk away. To do more would imply that you are testing UUID itself, and that would be wrong — it's not the subject-under-test and doesn't belong to you.

(And in general do not aim for / expect 100% coverage. That's insane. 80% is a good goal.)

Comment: Definitely agree on the code coverage point. 

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know about not reaching 100% however when I saw the code like this I thought that it would be quick to test it and it interested me how to do it exactly. I solved it, as @Fogmeister suggested, by adding an init() and testing if it set all values correctly.

Comment: Yep, it's a valuable technique.